# Given two lines, how do I find the plane?

Tags: calculus, vectors, cross-product

$$r_1(t) = \langle t, 2t, 3t\rangle$$
$$r_2(t) = \langle3t, t, 8t\rangle$$

I found $\mathbf{n} = \langle13,1,-5\rangle$

Can I just plug in say $P_0 = (0,0,0)$ and get 
$13x+y-5z = 0$?

Comment: Yes, looks good

Comment: Yes, since $ \ t = 0 \ $ gives the origin for both lines, that point will serve well, and the cross product looks to be alright, so the equation for the plane should be correct.